# Mantener formato DataGridView al hacer filtro C#

Tags: c#, datagrid

resulta que tengo un **`DatagridView`** con el siguiente formato **`(ver Imagen)`** (Naranja -> Desactivados los checkBox y blanco -> Activados los CheckBox, resulta que quiero hacer un filtro sobre este **`DataGridView`** y lo hago así:

```
public void filtrarPorClave()
{
    DataView dv = (DataTable)dgvExistencia.DataSource.DefaultView;
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("CLAVE_ART LIKE '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text);
}
```

El filtro me realiza correctamente, pero me quita el formato, alguna forma de mantener el formato al filtrar los datos?

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como estas añadiendo el "formato"?

Comment: @Pikoh  el formato lo hago al momento de cargar mi aplicación, básicamente activo todos los checkBox y comparo dos columnas diferentes, si encuentra coincidencias desactiva el Check y pinta de naranja, caso contrario mantiene activado el CheckBox y pinta de blanco la fila...

Comment: Ahi está el problema. El formateo de un datagridview debe hacerse en algun evento que se dispare cuando este se redibuja,por ejemplo en `RowPrePaint`

Comment: @SilvestreSilva ¿puedes considerar que - después de aplicar el filtro - recorras las filas del `DataGridview` y le apliques el formato a la(s) fila(s)?

Comment: Si lo estableces desde propiedades el formato se matendra

Comment: Esto es para windows-form o WPF?

Answer (score 2):

Tenes 2 formas de solucionar este inconveniente.

1- Establecerlo desde las propiedades del datagridview

2- En vez de hacerlo en la carga de tu aplicación, realizas un metodo que tenga esa función y luego llamas a la misma cada vez que cargues o filtres el dgv

Espero que te sirva la respuesta.

Saludos